# Statistical eigenvalue analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a linear dynamic system of the form:

```
x' = Ax + Bu
```

Some of the parameters used in forming the system matrix A are random variables with known probability density functions.

Is there a way to determine the distribution (or at least some features of the distribution) of the system eigenvalues?

Obviously, it would be possible numerically by performing a Monte Carlo simulation, but I'm interested in whether there is an analytical approach.